# Why do I get "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'." when I try to use sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Why do I get this error

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

when I try to use `sp_executesql`?

Comment: How are you trying to execute it? In T-SQL? From a program? Are you passing the required "@statement" parameter?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Sounds like you're calling sp_executesql with a VARCHAR statement, when it needs to be NVARCHAR.

e.g. This will give the error because @SQL needs to be NVARCHAR

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

So:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: This does work, but the other answer (from Daniel Renshaw) is WAY more useful, most of the time. (since it doesn't need the pointless variable declaration)

Answer (score 24):

The solution is to put an N in front of both the type and the SQL string to indicate it is a double-byte character string:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) 
SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had missed another tiny detail: I forgot the brackets "(100)" behind NVARCHAR.