# Why we should not use varchar in "sp_executesql"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Whenever I try to use `varchar` in `sp_executesql` it's always throwing the following error:

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Is there any reason we should use `nvarchar`?

If "exec" allows us to use varchar, why not sp_executesql?

**Sample Code:**

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @SQLString **varchar**(500);--**we need to use nvarchar!! but why?**

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);


SET @SQLString =
     'SELECT nationalidnumber, NationalIDNumber, Title, LoginID
       FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee 
       WHERE nationalidnumber = @BusinessEntityID';
SET @ParmDefinition = '@BusinessEntityID int';

SET @IntVariable = 14417807;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;

SET @IntVariable = 109;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```

Comment: Please show us your code...

Comment: Added my sample code with the question-Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743890/why-do-i-get-procedure-expects-parameter-statement-of-type-ntext-nchar-nvar

Comment: Because `sp_executesql` is written to *expect* a SQL statement as a type `nvarchar` - that's just a design decision the guys made when writing that stored procedure. That's the way it's designed - so you need to comply with this.

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl He asked about the reason. The link which you have given is not the reason

Comment: the main reason is provide support for Unicode characters

Comment: My guess would be that specifying unicode rather than non-unicode is simply more modern practice, for many good reasons (it might even help to mitigate against malicious attacks on dynamic SQL based on bad character encoding.) The reason exec supports non-Unicode is for backwards compatibility -- exec is as old as the hills and changing it would break lots of existing code, whereas sp_executesql was introduced (with unicode parameters from the start) in SQL Server 2008. But to know for sure, you'd have to ask Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments, So to use "unicode" they designed "sp_executesql" to accept only "nvarchar"

Comment: sp_executesql is an extended procedure, those are picky about parameter datatypes, and there's no automatic coercion unlike other places

Answer (score 0):

[Msdn0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

> **EXECUTE**
>
> Executes a command string or character string within a
> Transact-SQL batch
>
> **@string_variable**
>
> Is the name of a local variable. @string_variable can be any **char**, **varchar**, **nchar**, or **nvarchar** data type. These include the (max) data
>
> **types. [N] 'tsql_string'**
>
> Is a constant string. tsql_string can be any **nvarchar** or **varchar** data type. If the N is included, the string is interpreted as nvarchar
> data type.

[Msdn1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

> **sp_executesql**
>
> **[ @stmt = ] statement**
>
> Is a Unicode string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch

So it needs variables in Unicode by design (as @marc_s said). And as @MattGibson commented it is a modern practice to use Unicode.

[Msdn2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

> **nvarchar** [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length **Unicode** string data.

[Msdn3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> **varchar** [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length, **non-Unicode** string data.

And here you can read more about difference between `varchar` and `nvarchar`:
[What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)