# Inconsistent results using a VarChar or NVarChar parameter with EXECUTE [master].[sys].[sp_executesql]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have built up the T-SQL variable `@Foo` over many lines of code.

If `@Foo` is declared as `VarChar(MAX)`, the immediately following `PRINT` statement outputs what I expect (5,421 characters).

However, the further following `EXECUTE` statement fails because it requires an `NVarChar` parameter.

When I change the declaration of `@Foo` to `NVarChar(MAX)`, the `PRINT` statement only prints out a subset (3,902 characters) of what I am expecting. The output is truncated.

`@Foo` is the concatenation of a number of variables, all of which are `VarChar(MAX)`. Before I go up the chain, changing all predecessor variables as `NVarChar(MAX)`, to continue testing, I was wondering if anyone has an idea about this inconsistent behaviour.

```
PRINT @Foo

EXECUTE [master].[sys].[sp_executesql] @Foo
```

Many thanks.

Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MSDN PRINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) states,

> A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a
>   non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode
>   string. Longer strings are truncated. The **varchar(max)** and
>   **nvarchar(max)** data types are truncated to data types that are no
>   larger than **varchar(8000)** and **nvarchar(4000)**.

`sp_executesql` doesn't apply these restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Alex. So, do you have any idea how I could use sp_executesql to run a, say, 5,000 character T-SQL expression contained in a variable? I seem to be in a catch-22 - sp_executesql requires NVarChar, and NVarChar is capped at 4,000 characters. One hacky thing I could do would be to put the execute statement inside the loop where I am currently iteratively concatenating T-SQL code to cumulatively execute after the loop, but that is not ideal. Thanks.

Comment: Ther is no such restriction for `sp_executesql`. See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Hi Alex. I think that my user experience is inconsistent with your feedback.
I get the following message when I execute a VarChar parameter:
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Also, this link seems to say the opposite:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743890/why-do-i-get-procedure-expects-parameter-statement-of-type-ntext-nchar-nvar

Comment: As `sp_executesql` specification reads `@stmt` (first argument) must be nvarchar(length) `max` is ok. The value must start with N `declare @stmt nvarchar(max) = N'select....'`. "On 64-bit servers, the size of the string is limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of nvarchar(max)." Read the link above again.