# Running a conditional sql script dependent on existence of database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to automate a sql script to add a column to existing databases on a given system. The script will be run on a system with one database or a different one. The script should not cause error in any of the cases:
1. One of the two databases exists
2. Both databases exist
3. Neither database exists.

I tried this but I keep getting error when the database 'DatabaseName' does not exist. I want the script to be ignored in that case.

```
IF DB_ID('DatabaseName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'DatabaseName Exists'
    IF COL_LENGTH('[DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table]', 'NewColumn') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table]
            ADD [NewColumn] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
            PRINT 'Modified DatabaseName.Table'
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'DatabaseName Does Not Exist' 
        -- therefore do nothing
    END
```

This gives me the error:

```
Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Database 'DatabaseName' does not exist.
```

I had also tried different variations of 
    Use 'DatabaseName' 
with the same or similar errors because they are not existent.

To clarify: it is okay if it does not exist. I am just trying to handle the error gracefully so an installation continues

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: good point, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Is the Wix tag necessary, as I didn't see Wix mentioned in the original question? I was brought here thinking it was a Wix related issue.

Comment: @Francis, sorry to bring you here with undue cause. I am using this solution in conjunction to wix but I see your point. Removing the tag.

Comment: No worries @MMiles. Always happy to help regardless. Glad your issues were resolved and thanks for the cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL.  The problem is occurring during the *compilation* phase of the code.  Dynamic SQL will "hide" the reference to the database from the initial compilation phase.

For instance, in SQL Server, this looks like:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('[DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table]', 'NewColumn') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        exec sp_executesql N'
ALTER TABLE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Table]
    ADD [NewColumn] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0';
        PRINT 'Modified DatabaseName.Table'
    END
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you @GordonLinoff

Comment: Sidenote in case anyone is trying this out and getting 'Procedure expects parameter @statement of type nvarchar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2743920/4877765
Just define the sql statement as nvarchar before running

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try catch block:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute code if error
END CATCH;
```

Comment: While I like this solution for catching errors when something might go wrong, it did not solve my issue of my nonexistent database causing an error. The dynamic sql statement in @GordonLinoff 's answer solved that issue. 
Upvote for try/catch blocks in sql, which I was previously unaware of. Thank you.